# GWT - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpectedly unable to access Enum.createValueOfMap via reflection

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT and i imported existing GWT web project into EClipse IDE and tried to compile it through "GWT Compile" in Eclipse but I am getting below exception.

Project looks to be properly set up in Eclipse.
I am using GWT 2.7.0.

I tried to find solution for this but could not find the exact matching one.

Could anyone please help me in resolving this?

```
[ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpectedly unable to access Enum.createValueOfMap via reflection. Likely a dependency on the com.google.gwt.user.User module is missing.
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.writeEnumValueOfMethod(GwtAstBuilder.java:2793)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.processEnumType(GwtAstBuilder.java:2425)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.endVisit(GwtAstBuilder.java:1861)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder$AstVisitor.endVisit(GwtAstBuilder.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1382)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.process(GwtAstBuilder.java:3058)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater$UnitProcessorImpl.process(CompilationStateBuilder.java:141)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.process(JdtCompiler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:470)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:985)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:339)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:580)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:513)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:499)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:668)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:255)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:206)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:158)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:127)
```

Comment: Below jar files are added to /WEB-INF/lib and present under class path:

Comment: ganymed-ssh2-build250.jar
gson-1.7.1.jar
gwt-comet-1.1.6.jar
gwt-servlet.jar
gwt-user.jar
gwttheme.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
smartgwt.jar
vDBServices0409.jar
vFoundation0409.jar

Comment: Search  for you <module>.gwt.xml and look, if it inherits the mentioned Moduke